# How do you use copyToRealmOrUpdate for a list?

Tags: android, realm

This is some code in my Android App:

```
public class Offer extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
```

}

In my service class:

```
  RealmList<Offer> currentLocalMerchantOfferList = currentLocalMerchant.getOffers();
   RealmList<Offer> findIncomingMerchantOfferList = findIncomingMerchant.getOffers();
                                if (!EqualsUtil.areEqual(currentLocalMerchantOfferList, findIncomingMerchantOfferList)) {
                                    currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(findIncomingMerchantOfferList == null ? null : realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(findIncomingMerchantOfferList));
                                }
```

I get `compile` error:

```
error: incompatible types: bad type in conditional expression
                                currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(findIncomingMerchantOfferList == null ? null : realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(findIncomingMerchantOfferList));
```

Am I using `copyToRealmOrUpdate` correctly? If not, how do you use it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(findIncomingMerchantOfferList)` returns a `List<T>` and not a `RealmList<T>`.

RealmList represents `many-relationship` to another object type. Therefore, these randomly inserted objects aren't a many-relationship, therefore they are not RealmList.

In fact, they are internally returned as an `ArrayList`.

The way you can change your code to accomodate is by:

```
currentLocalMerchant.getOffers().clear();
currentLocalMerchant.getOffers().addAll(realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(findIncomingMerchantOfferList));
```

Comment: I need to update items in list in same orders. Is method "addAll()" do this?

Comment: I mean, it's just `for(Item item: items) { targetList.add(item) }` pretty much

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to use copyToRealmOrUpdate method to set value. Just set the value that you have

```
 if (!EqualsUtil.areEqual(currentLocalMerchantOfferList, findIncomingMerchantOfferList)) {
                                        currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(findIncomingMerchantOfferList)
                                    }
```

If findIncomingMerchant.getOffers() back to you persistent data than it will work perfectly.

Comment: Not work. I get error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object.

Comment: I already mentioned that you can add only persistent to persistent data. I think you don't understand my point. Apply this currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(realm.copyfromRealm(findIncomingMerchantOfferList))

Comment: currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(realm.copyToRealm(findIncomingMerchantOfferList)); But I geterror: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that List<E> conforms to RealmList<Offer>
                                currentLocalMerchant.setOffers(realm.copyToRealm(findIncomingMerchantOfferList));